# Bind new property value of a custom control with a property of its parent class

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

(VB.NET VS2010) I was using library of custom controls inherited of basic system controls in several projects (call them A-controls), and now I want to use components of a 3rd-party library  (call them B-controls) and for a easy integration of this components in my projects I want to create another custom library of components (call it C-Controls) which inherit of B-Controls but with same properties of A-Controls (same names of class and properties), the goal is just change library references in my projects.

My problem is, B-Controls has a B1-property which is similar to A1-property, so in my C-controls I have a component which directly inherits of a control of B-Controls and I added the similar A1-property with same name, so I have in C-Controls controls B1-Property and A1-property, and I would like synchronize their values when they change.

Is it possible? Is it possible without modifying events of each controls?

The explanation could be a mess… if it is needed I'll complete with more.

Thanks in advance.

- A-Control-Component (inherits System component)

  - A1-Property
- B-Control-Component

  - B1-Property
- C-Control-Component (inherits 3rd-party library) really its name is as A-Control-Component too

  - B1-Property (by inheritance)
  - A1-Property (similar behalf than B1-Property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if I understood you in any way correctly you can use the Get/Set methods of the properties to syncronize them by using a single backend variable

```
Private _MyValue As Integer

Public Property A1Property As Integer
  Get
    Return _MyValue
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
    _MyValue = value
  End Set
End Property

Public Property B1Property As Integer
  Get
    Return _MyValue
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
    _MyValue = value
  End Set
End Property
```

What happens now is that every time you change either `A1Property` or `B1Property` actually the same variable is changed. Likewise this value is returned if you query the current value of either `A1Property` or `B1Property`. Therefore they are synced.

Let me know if that was what you are asking.

**Edit:**

If you don't actually define `B1Property` (which might be the case, reading your question again) you can just Get/Set `B1Property` from your new `A1Property`

```
Public Property A1Property As Integer
  Get
    Return Me.B1Property
  End Get
  Set(value As Integer)
    Me.B1Property = value
  End Set
End Property
```

This would do the same thing.